# Why When Build to APK and Run at Mobile the Screen Graphic Look Wrecked ? Unity3D Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Could someone help me with look at the screenshot i post ?

[image]

[image]

Look at to two picture above. Why in Unity Editor it is not a problem, but when build in apk and run in device mobile it become like this ??

Could someone figure out what happen and give the solution ?

Thanks

Denis

Comment: This is a result of wrong config. e.g try to set texture compression to ETC, and sprite format to 16 bits,  Rendering to forward, graphic APIs to OpenGLES2.

Comment: Hi @Bijan Could you post the step how to set it  ? I am a little confused to look where is the menu, please. Thanks

Comment: By the way i can't find the menu you say. I am using texture type : Sprite (2D and UI).

Comment: Could Someone help me ? I have set compression with no warning, rendering to forward and graphic API to OpenGLES2 BUT still have the same screen show above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FINALLY GOT THE ANSWER**

That's is a glitch from setting a camera.

Look at this screenshot below :

[image]

Look at the **"Clear Flags"** is setting to : **Don't Clear**. It is cause the screen graphic like above.

Change it to **"Skybox"** or **anyelse** except for **"Don't Clear"**.

Thanks